# Как проверить почту на существование на Python

Tags: python, imap

Каким образом можно проверить почту на валидность ( существует ли она ).
Я видел много способов, но все они либо не рабочие либо они все очень длинные, мне же нужно что бы этот процесс был довольно быстрым. Был бы признателен если ответ был бы в видел кода с комментариями.

Comment: почтовое имя? - думаю никак. или же почтовый сервер?

Comment: Именно почтовый адрес

Comment: Это невозможно. Вы можете проверить только [MX-запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Запись_MX) на домене. А полный адрес почты обрабатывается самим сервером по настраиваемым алгоритмам (например, можно перенаправлять почту с несуществующих адресов на один из ящиков).

Comment: Понял, спасибо ща ответы

Comment: Спам базу составить хотите? Обычно это на живца делается, то есть либо из открытых источников (списки рассылки), либо путём ожидания ответа.